# JAXB Binding File Error (Is already in use. Error)

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to make a JAXB binding file. I have an XSD which i has a chain of imports of three more XSDs.

So Its like A-->B-->C-->D

When I made the maven file under configuration I declared the only A in the "source" tag in my pom file.

But the conflict is in file C. This is my binding file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd" version="2.1">

    <jxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true" />

    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../Work/XSDFiles/APIDefinition.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='MPLS-VPNListItem']">
            <jxb:class name="MPLS_VPNListItem" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

</jxb:bindings>
```

APIDefinition.xsd is my file C. When I run it i get the error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: A class/interface with the same name "com.advantis.sch.api3pc4.xmlschema.api.MPLSVPNListItem" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
```

I also tried putting the main file (A) in the schemaLocation, that one fails even more badly saying it wasn't able to find the tag at all.

My Binding file and XSD files are in different folders.

Can you please help me out with this. If you need more info, please do let me know.

Comment: Could you try a completely different classname? I think underscores are ignored in the binding file too, so it generates a class that still has the same name.

Comment: That is what I did, right after posting this. That works just fine. From what I recall, JAXB strips "-" when making class names. It could be that the real conflict could be on some other file. I am just not able to find it. The XSD are more than 3k lines long.

Comment: Yeah, the conflict is in this file and some other that defines the same class name. If the types with the same name should be the same class, you should be able to get it working without a binding file. Just make sure those 2 types have the same namespace.

Comment: I was correct in getting the class right. I notice that the binding file ignores the _ in the class name. So it does not add it to the final class name, hence the conflict

Comment: I was able to get it done by adding `underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"` in the gloablBindings, after a little bit more Googling. The problem was MPLS_VPNListItem, the _ was just ignored. Hence the conflict. After adding it, it all goes fine.

Comment: Didn't know that one existed. Good to know, thanks.